# Gearing your Templar with class opposite?

Tags: diablo-iii

When leveling a new character as an INT based class (Witch Doctor, Wizard, Etc...) how does one gear the Templar?

Since Loot 2.0 and "smartloot", it's not as easy to get gear for something besides your primary attribute. So doesn't that make it very difficult to gear someone like the Templar if he is running with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to gear your *Templar* if you are using an Int based class(WD/Wiz, which "Etc." are you talking about?).

1. Use your Barbarian/Crusader hero to farm some Str-based items
2. You can also re-roll main stat on an item so that it would be beneficial to your follower
3. Be patient and wait for some drops, Loot 2.0 and Smartloot still gives you some "useless" items once in a while
4. Play with somebody else, ask him/her to give you decent items for the follower of your choice

Comment: Another option is to earn Bloodshards in Rifts on the non-STR class, then switch over to the Crusader/Barbarian and gamble with Kadala.